# Intersection boolen shader

Tags: modifiers, intersection

How can I make a shader that will change if two objects intersect? (More precisely, I need to understand how to calculate the factor for a mix shader using vector maths)

Comment: Could you detail a bit : why vector math specifically and have you tried other common methods like Object Coordinates or even Ambient Occlusion node?